# git bring latest new code from forked out branch

Tags: git, github

I have a brach `abc`.

I forked our my own branch out of it. Say branch `def`.

1 month has now passed.

Multiple people have checked in into `abc` branch which fixes major issues. 
My `def` branch has my multiple changes and also from other people.

How can I bring the changes which people did on branch `abc` into my branch `def` so that I can check how my code behaves with latest code changes?

I cannot create a new branch of `abc` and cherry pick from `def` branch as `def` branch is being shared with mutiple people and they just want `def` branch to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `def` branch has contribution from other developers, [rebasing](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) that `def` branch on top of `abc` isn't a good option, as it would change its history.

The easiest way remains to [merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) `abc` to `def`.

```
git checkout def
git merge abc

x--x--x--x--x--x (abc)          x--x--x--x--x--x (abc)
      \                     =>        \         \
       y--y--y (def)                   y--y--y---M (def)
```